Inserting CSS code to customize GUI of Sharepoint 365
We start using Sharepoint 365 (online). We used to work with Sharepoint Server 2019 (on-premise) version.
Using classic interface, we tried to customize navigation of Sharepoint with CSS code but could not find Script Editor webpart in menu. Using custom script options were already enabled in Sharepoint Admin Center. We don't plan to use modern interface for now.
Does anyone know how to fix that issue or another method to do?
Thanks in advanced.

Are you using communication site or team site in SharePoint Online?

We are using classic team site.

do you have access to script editor or content editor web part?

As the script editor web part is not supported in modern SharePoint, we are unable to insert CSS or JavaScript directly. We have to use SPFx based react script editor web part to add custom CSS or JavaScript to modern SharePoint Online pages.
Reference:
Build your first SharePoint Framework Extension.
Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Application Extensions.
Step By Step Procedure To Add A JS File To All Pages In A SPFx Modern Pages Using SharePoint Framework Extension.

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.
